# iphonesdk searchbar on nsmutable array

Tags: iphone, objective-c

is there anyway i can use search bar on the nsmutable array . i have data like this :

```
 [listOfItems addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
     @"Pakistan", 
     @A country with lot of salt mines", 
     nil]
 ];
```

i m displaying Pakistan on a table view and when click on it i went on the other view with in info about it.

i seen search-bar with array and dictionary but couldn't found on mutable array please help.
thanks in advance

Comment: if you could not found mutable array then how can you find it in search-bar with array and dictionary ??? Please make sure you are asking the question in better way.Even i m getting confused..what you want to do either search or pass the array to another ViewController??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is delegate method in searchbar that can help you like:

`-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText`

Then you can use predicate to filter data

```
NSPredicate * predicate =  [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(title CONTAINS[cd] %@), searchText];
self.displayedData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[self.allData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
```

Answer (score 2):

NSMutableArray inherits from NSArray, so it's the same.